# Adding MVC support to WebForms website project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

We have a huge webfomrs website (Not web app. No `.csproj` file). We do not intend to migrate to MVC completely, but we do have some requirements where MVC would make much more sense than webfroms. I read up on the subject and my understanding is that what I need is to add the assemblies, register them in the `web.config` and add all the registrations in the `global.asax` file. This is easier in my case, since we already use routing anyway, so that is already taken care of.

I decided the best approach would be to install the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` package via `nuget` in to the website. This seems to have done the trick. My only issue is that I cannot find where to add `Controller` classes. When I want to add a new item, I get all the templates, incl. Razor pages, Razor layouts, Web API controller (v1 and v2), but no MVC controller item type. So how do I create controllers? I could just create a plain `.cs` file and do this manually, but I would really rather not. I could also create a new MVC web app and create the controllers there and then copy them, but this makes the integration very awkward. Makes the whole thing harder to sell to the higher-ups, if you know what I mean.

Is there any way to add this tooling support to an existing asp.net website?

**EDIT:** I managed to create a `Controller` manually in the `App_Code` forlder, and everything works fine. I still don't see the IDE support for MVC, so I need to create all the `Controllers` and `Views` manually. This would make adoption very difficult.

Comment: MVC and Webforms at same time!!Not a good practice and will make things more complex as I think.

Comment: @NipunAmbastha - Well it seems the rest of the world (incl. Microsoft) does not agree :) You can read up on `Asp.net vNext`

Comment: Oh Man!! I missed it! Tech changes so fast... like a Ferrari :P
Thanks for pointing me out.
Glad learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

You may have figured out a lot by now and I am sure you would have added references to the following Assemblies too:

- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Routing
- System.Web.Abstractions

To be able to add a controller, you may create any class that derives from `Controller` and map the same in the routing logic. This should work.

Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

first of all take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528117/WebForms-vs-MVC) article and then get started. if you have your own routing in asp.net web form and if you think it will compatible with mvc routing, there is no other issue about adding MVC support to your application. you don't need to add an MVC project to your solution neither, you just need to reference `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`. you just have to add a controllers and Views folder and then simply create controller classes and views. 
but if you want to do this, I advice you to take the advantages of MVC routing in web form, you can read about its advantages. take a look at [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx/) article to achieve the same goal.